# How do I group districts by country in a for loop in python?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a dataframe with countries and districts, I would like to group all districts by country.

This is my code:

```
sa_d = []
ma_d = []
za_d = []
mo_d = []
for d, f in dn['interview_country', 'interview_district']:
    if d == 'South Africa':
      sa_d.append(f)
    elif d == 'Malawi':
      ma_d.append(f)
    elif d == 'Zambia':
      za_d.append(f)
    elif d == 'Mozambique':
      zo_d.append(f)
```

I would like to have a list of districts for each country as an output.
Instead I get an error:

```
KeyError: ('interview_country', 'interview_district')
```

Comment: could you give an example `dn`?

Comment: Use a `dict` mapping country names to entries instead of 4 lists, then you don't need all those `if/elif`. The actual problem seems to lie somewhere else, though.

Comment: would you mind to post a sample fragment (once again asking)?

Comment: @Adam.Er8 dn is the name of my dataframe             dn = pd.read_sql_table('district_vw', engine)                dn = dn[["interview_country", "interview_district", "upload_date", "count"]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another pair of brackets (assuming pandas data-frame):

```
sa_d = []
ma_d = []
za_d = []
mo_d = []
for d, f in dn[['interview_country', 'interview_district']].values.tolist():
    if d == 'South Africa':
      sa_d.append(f)
    elif d == 'Malawi':
      ma_d.append(f)
    elif d == 'Zambia':
      za_d.append(f)
    elif d == 'Mozambique':
      zo_d.append(f)
```

Comment: I tried adding the brackets but I get this      for d, f in dn[['interview_country', 'interview_district']]:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)